# Implementing threshold for requests in real time in Springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gemfire

I'm developing a rest service with spring boot. I need to validate the threshold for each request by user, the threshold is currently maintained in Database. Everyday the threshold for the user should be reset to zero. 
Currently I'm connecting to database to pull the numbers to validate and updating the daily count.
This is causing performance issues and the throughput is very low(I could process only 25< requests per second).

I'm trying to Implement Gemfire to cache and process , But worried about accumulating incremental changes to shared data.

Any alternate ways or help is appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to implement rateLimiter?

Comment: Not rate limiter, we should process only the requests within the threshold for the specific user on that day